# Android: Google Data API - 401 Token Invalid Error

Tags: android, google-data-api, accountmanager

Well, I tried using Account Manager and I am getting "401 Token Invalid" error. What can be the reason.

Debug Log

```
Account name = xxxxxx@gmail.com
Token is : DQAAALIAAAAh-xxxxxxx
Starting Google DATA API loader-----------------
Inside Google Notebook loader-----------------
Setting Token : DQAAALIAAAAh-xxxxx
Url is : https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
Exception getting docs feed : 401 Token invalid
Done Google DATA API loader-----------------
```

Sample Code:

```
Log.d("Main","\tInside GoogleDATA API -----------------");
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
    Log.d("Main","\tSetting Token : " + authToken);
    headers.setGoogleLogin(authToken);
    headers.gdataVersion="3.0";
    transport.defaultHeaders = headers;
    AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
    parser.namespaceDictionary = Namespace.DICTIONARY;
    transport.addParser(parser);
    try {
        DocsUrl url = DocsUrl.forDefaultPrivateFull();
        DocumentListFeed feed = DocumentListFeed.executeGet(transport,url);
        List<DocumentListEntry> docs = feed.docs;
        Log.d("Main","\tDocs count = " + docs.size());
        for (Iterator iterator = docs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            DocumentListEntry documentListEntry = (DocumentListEntry) iterator
                    .next();
            Log.d("Main","\t\tDocument title is : " + documentListEntry.title);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Main","Exception getting docs feed : " + e.getMessage());
            //handleException(e);
    }
    Log.d("Main","\tDone GoogleDATA API -----------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should see how it works on this website http://n01se.net/gmapez/start.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.